# How to edit ufw .rules files?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

Where can I learn the syntax and options available in **ufw** configuration files such as `/etc/ufw/before.rules`? I have searched the ufw manual, ufw wiki, and on DuckDuckGo and nowhere have I been able to find documentation for this.

Comment: I found the answer on our sister site in a couple searches using your terms: https://askubuntu.com/questions/409013/how-do-you-create-an-app-profile-for-ufw

Comment: Can't find it on that page. I'm looking for documentation on the syntax used in `/etc/ufw/before.rules` like `*nat` and `:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]`  and `COMMIT`. I've been able to piece it together for what I need but still found no comprehensive documentation. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1335940) was especially helpful.